# Can I validate my Sequence container before running it? (Visual Studio)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, event-handling

I have made a onError Event Handler in Visual Studio for SQL Server that send me an E-Mail if the package is failing during the loading process.
I have a master package which contains some other packages and if one of it Fails I get one E-Mail. But if the Connection is failing in every Package I get an E-Mail from every Package. How can I Change that so that I get only one E-Mail if the Connection is failing in every package?

Or is it possible to test the Connection before the packages will run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onError event handler will be invoked every time your package encounters an error, so if you only want one email, don't send the email in the onError event handler.

Instead, do something in the onError handler like:

- Update a counter (number of errors)
- Set a Boolean to True (True for    "there were errors", false for
  "there were no errors")
- Build your email string, adding a message for each error, but don't send it

Then finally in the post execute event of the package (which will only get called once), send your email, if there were any errors.